# Is There A way to combine Firebase phone-auth with custom token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to combine Firebase phone-auth with custom token so that you don't give up on phone number verification and also be able to integrate seamlessly with your own backend authentication logic

Comment: What would "combine" mean in this context? Why would one need phone auth if using your own backend auth? Pick one. Assuming you are looking for multi-factor authentication, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGCLPiR_0Lg&feature=youtu.be&t=1432) may help.

Comment: @Kato It was Multi-factor Authentication I just wanted to achieve here, Is There Timeline to expect those features in the above video to be released?